# QProcess doesn't kill/terminate the process if be defined on heap

Tags: c++, static, heap-memory, kill-process, qprocess

I want to kill/terminate the process that's I created when my app exit:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPushButton w; w.show();
    struct Lambda {
        static void run() {
            static QProcess p; //version 1
//            QProcess& p = *new QProcess(qApp); //version 2
            p.connect(qApp, &QApplication::aboutToQuit, &p, &QProcess::kill);
            p.connect(qApp, &QApplication::aboutToQuit, &p, &QProcess::terminate);
            p.connect(qApp, &QApplication::aboutToQuit, &p, &QProcess::close);
            p.connect(qApp, &QApplication::aboutToQuit, &p, &QProcess::deleteLater);
            p.start("caffeinate -d");
        }
    };
    QtConcurrent::run(Lambda::run);
    return a.exec();
}
```

With version 1: my app run as I'm expecting: create and kill the process successfully but when exit the app, QCreator report: "QProcess: Destroyed while process ("caffeinate") is still running."

With version 2: my app can start the process but cannot kill/terminate the process on exit, and there are no report like above.

I just want to ask why when created on the heap, QProcess cannot be kill like stative version? Thanks!

(I used struct Lambda because of I cannot use c++11 lambda in my project)

Comment: Killing, _then_ terminating, _then_ closing the process makes no sense to me...

Comment: What is this I don't even ... you managed to make quite a mess of threads, external processes, potential double deletes, not waiting for termination, random termination signals, cross-thread connections, unclear objects lifetimes, widgets used as top-level windows... it's a miracle it doesn't explode right away.

Comment: How can you say version works and **kills** the process, If the message is: `QProcess: Destroyed while process ("caffeinate") is still running.`. Still running means it was not **killed**

Comment: @fjardon: actually, the message is misleading; the `QProcess` destructor kills the process if it's still running (but complains out loud).

Comment: @fjardon: I check this: ps aux | grep caffeinate

Comment: @Matteo: those connects are just explaining which cases I tried, I just need one of them. This small app is just to explaining the problem I'm trying to resolve. And, can you explain: "mess of threads". Thanks!

Comment: @Matteo: I think so, destructor willl be called automatic for static variable but not with dynamic variable except we call explicit with delete

Comment: @MatteoItalia Indeed, the message comes from the destructor. So it proves the signal/slot connection wasn't done and the program is **not working**. This explains why the second version doesn't even kill the process: the destructor is not called. Both versions suffer from the same flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr

In both cases, the signals aren't delivered; in the first case the destructor kills the process, in the second one it doesn't even have a chance to run.

In general, your code is a nice compendium of almost all the no-dos with `QObject`, `QThread`, signals and the like; ***do read [Threads and QObjects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html) before doing anything with threads, QObjects and signals in Qt.*** This is essential information without which you'll only do a mess like this.* Also [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects) wiki article provides a good rundown of the "right way" to use threads with Qt.

---

### Detailed explanation

Let's call the main thread *thread A* and the thread started by `QtConcurrent::run` *thread B*.

#### Case 1

When `run` is run from the second thread, `p` is created, so it has [thread affinity](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity) with thread *B*. For this reason, all the `connect` you perform on it are [*queued connections*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) (the default for `connect` is `AutoConnection`, which uses a `QueuedConnection` if the connected objects have different thread affinity - and `qApp` is created in *thread A*).

The problem is, queued connections work only if the receiving thread has an event loop running (they are implemented as a [`sendEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#sendEvent), so if there's no event loop processing events in the target thread they only pile up in the event queue), while here `run` returns right after starting the process.

So, `kill`, `terminate`, `close` and `deleteLater` are never called. Notice that:

- calling `deleteLater` in this case would have been an error anyway, since it would be trying to do a `delete` on a `static` object;
- neither `kill` nor `terminate` are synchronous, so to make sure that the process is dead before going on you would have needed also a `waitForFinished`;
- also, potentially the thread that has been spun by `QtConcurrent::run` is going to be dead after `run` terminates<sup>1</sup>; this is definitely a bad thing, because you are going to have `QObject`s laying around with thread affinity to a thread that is dead. I don't know how gracefully `sendEvent` handles this situation.

Anyhow, when the program ends, the `p`'s destructor is invoked automatically as a normal part of the shutdown of a C++ application<sup>2</sup>; [as documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#dtor.QProcess), the destructor of `QProcess` terminates the process it is linked to if it's still running (but also writes out the "scary message" you saw).

#### Case 2

As in case 1, you are creating the `QProcess` with *thread B* affinity; so all that we said above about events not being delivered & co. still applies.

There are three main differences here:

- you are setting the parent of `p` to `qApp`, which lives in the main thread; this is explicitly disallowed, all parent-child relationships between QObjects must exist between objects with the same thread affinity; probably you are getting some warning message in console about this fact (`setParent` explicitly checks if the objects live in the same thread, I expect `QObject`'s constructor to do the same);
- in this case, the `deleteLater` could have been appropriate (if you had an event loop spinning), as you allocated with `new`;
- but most importantly, here `p`'s destructor is never invoked, as it has been allocated with `new` and no one is calling `delete` on it; for this reason, the started process keeps running (also, you have a small memory leak).

---

So, what would have been the been the correct way to deal with this? Personally, I would have avoided threads and signals altogether. The starting a process is already asynchronous so you could have simply done:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QProcess p;
    p.start("caffeinate -d");
    QPushButton w; w.show();
    int ret = a.exec();
    p.close();
    return ret;
}
```

as always with threads, event queues, signals and the like: don't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

---

#### Footnotes

1. In practice in this case you probably won't notice because `QtConcurrent` uses the global thread pool, which kills spun threads only after 30 seconds of idling.
2. General tip: you typically don't want "complicated" objects to be destroyed in this way, since the `main` has already terminated, so (1) this makes debugging more complicated and (2) if you have Qt objects that depend on the `QApplication` still being alive (typically, everything in QtGui and QtWidgets) you'll start to get weird crashes at program termination.